# Jpa creation failed

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have got the following error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeesServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeesRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeesRepository' defined in com.cgi.listeemployes.repository.EmployeesRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.cgi.listeemployes.repository.EmployeesRepository.findManagedEmployees(int)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cgi.listeemployes.repository.EmployeesRepository.findManagedEmployees(int)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cgi.listeemployes.repository.EmployeesRepository.findManagedEmployees(int)

I don't understand why.

```
public interface EmployeesRepository extends JpaRepository < Employee, Integer > {

  @Query("Select lastName FROM employee WHERE employee.managerId = employeeId")
  List < String > findManagedEmployees(int employeeId);
}
```

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeesRepository employeesRepository;

  public Optional < Employee > getEmployee(final int id) {
    return employeesRepository.findById(id);
  }

  public Iterable < Employee > getEmployees() {
    return employeesRepository.findAll();
  }

  public List < String > getManagedEmployees(int employeeId) {
    return employeesRepository.findManagedEmployees(employeeId);
  }

  public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    Employee savedEmployee = employeesRepository.save(employee);
    return savedEmployee;
  }

  public void deleteEmployee(final int id) {
    employeesRepository.deleteById(id);
  }

}
```

```
 @Service
 public class EmployeeService {

   @Autowired
   private EmployeesRepository employeesRepository;

   public Optional < Employee > getEmployee(final int id) {
     return employeesRepository.findById(id);
   }

   public Iterable < Employee > getEmployees() {
     return employeesRepository.findAll();
   }

   public List < String > getManagedEmployees(int employeeId) {
     return employeesRepository.findManagedEmployees(employeeId);
   }

   public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
     Employee savedEmployee = employeesRepository.save(employee);
     return savedEmployee;
   }

   public void deleteEmployee(final int id) {
     employeesRepository.deleteById(id);
   }

 }
```

Comment: How does your package structure look like? Do you have the @SpringBootApplication class in the hierarchy above everything else?

Answer (score 0):

set the query to native SQL

```
@Query(value="Select last_name,firs_name,id FROM Employee WHERE employee.manager = ?1 ",nativeQuery=true)
```